# Flutter, Firebase: How to get the value of DocumentSnapshot type,

Tags: flutter, dart

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#document--query-snapshots

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/button_builder.dart';

import './register_page.dart';
import './signin_page.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(AuthExampleApp());
}

/// The entry point of the application.
///
/// Returns a [MaterialApp].
class AuthExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Firebase Example App',
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: AuthTypeSelector(),
        ));
  }
}

/// Provides a UI to select a authentication type page
class AuthTypeSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  // Navigates to a new page
  void _pushPage(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => page),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Firebase Example App"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: SignInButtonBuilder(
              icon: Icons.person_add,
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
              text: 'Registration',
              onPressed: () => _pushPage(context, RegisterPage()),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          Container(
            child: SignInButtonBuilder(
              icon: Icons.verified_user,
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
              text: 'Sign In',
              onPressed: () => _pushPage(context, SignInPage()),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          UserInformation(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    users.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        //↓Since doc is a Document Snapshot type, can the value be obtained by this reference method?
        print('${doc["full_name"]},${doc.runtimeType},${doc.reference}');

        //↓Since the return value of doc.data () is Map <String, dynamic>, 
        //there is no doubt that the value can be obtained in this form.
        print('${doc.data()["full_name"]}');
      });
    });

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: users.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        //ListViewをColumnの中に入れようとするとエラーが出るので、
        //↓Expandedでラップする必要がある。
        return Expanded(
          child: new ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(document.data()['full_name']),
                subtitle: new Text(document.data()['company']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
//result
flutter: Test Tarou,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/CgewvkhWjYeuW5trtFJ8)
flutter: Test Tarou
flutter: Test Jirou,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/CzyuXDo6TQuKATaOuKeU)
flutter: Test Jirou
flutter: Test Sabu,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/nww8lBuC8j2q05cXQBUA)
flutter: Test Sabu
flutter: Test Gorouxx,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/rQhMqCKtlwLPtiKK0azZ)
flutter: Test Gorouxx
flutter: Test Tarou,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/CgewvkhWjYeuW5trtFJ8)
flutter: Test Tarou
flutter: Test Jirou,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/CzyuXDo6TQuKATaOuKeU)
flutter: Test Jirou
flutter: Test Sabu,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/nww8lBuC8j2q05cXQBUA)
flutter: Test Sabu
flutter: Test Gorouxx,QueryDocumentSnapshot,DocumentReference(users/rQhMqCKtlwLPtiKK0azZ)
flutter: Test Gorouxx
```

I was experimenting with a sample FlutterFire documentation,
Two questions arose.

(1) As I wrote in the code comment,
querySnapshot.docs.forEach
I think the callback argument "doc" is of type DocumentSnapshot.

I can get the value of the "full_name" field of each document in the form of doc ["full_name"].

I'm wondering about this, is the DocumentSnapshot type a Map type?

It doesn't look like that when I look at document_snapshot.dart,
Even though it's not a Map type
Is it possible to get the value in the form of doc ["full_name"]?

Well, it's actually done.

Or rather, if we can get the value with doc ["full_name"], we don't need the data () method, right?
I will think.

(2) There are currently four documents in the'users' collection.

For some reason 4 documents are displayed on the console twice, 4✖️2 = 8 times.

I think the above code should display each document once, that is, four times.
Why is each document displayed twice?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `document.data()['full_name']` try and use `snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['full_name']` and also introduce length for your streambuilder. Sharing the appropriate code below :

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: users.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        
        return Expanded(
          child: new ListView.builder(
           itemCount: snapshot.data.size,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['full_name']),
                subtitle: new Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['company']),
              );
            }}).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Try and see if it works. It won't be perfectly bracket formatted but this should work.